# Updating the gridview in one form

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview

I have a small issue with [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx).

I have two forms, in one form the data will be populated by the DataGridView.

When we click on the column header of the gridview the other form will be opened with the corresponding column values.

I have done some manipulations on the data in form2 so before closing form2 I want to update the form1 gridview with these details...

I have seen some details like eventhandler attachment in form1, but I didn't find an exact answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Form 2 code**

```
    public event EventHandler<UpdatedEventArgs> updateEvent;

    public class UpdatedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string SomeVal { get; set; } // create custom event arg for your need
    }

    protected virtual void OnFirstUpdateEvent(UpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (updateEvent != null)
            updateEvent(this, e);
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatedEventArgs eventData = new UpdatedEventArgs(); 
        eventData.SomeVal = "test"; // set update event arguments, according to your need

        OnFirstUpdateEvent(eventData);
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

**Form 1 code**

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.updateEvent += new EventHandler<Form2.UpdatedEventArgs>(form2_updateEvent); // create event handler to update form 1 from form 2
        form2.Show();
    }

    void form2_updateEvent(object sender, Form2.UpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null && e.SomeVal != null)
        {
            // Do the update on Form 1 
            // depend on your event arguments update the grid  
            //MessageBox.Show(e.SomeVal); 
        }

    }
```

Comment: in form1 do i need to add any thing .. because u have mentioned these two in form2....

Answer (score 0):

By working with DataGrid you most likely use DataTable like a model. I would say pass like a parameter that DataTable to the form2 and manipulate THE SAME DataTable object in form2, so the changes made on its rows and commited will automatically reflect on form1.

Comment: would you pls take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131040/how-to-upload-a-images-from-our-own-system-and-display-that-image-in-one-of-the-p