# How to display an image from file system in a PictureBox in WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms

I have a small doubt regarding loading an image in PictureBox in WinForms.
I want to show an image file from file system in a `PictureBox` on my form, say `form1`.

I am doing Windows applications using C#.

I want to check the file type also say is it pdf/text/png/gif/jpeg.
Is it possible to programmatically open a file from file system using C#?
If anyone knows please give any idea or sample code for doing this.

**Modified Code**: I have done like this for opening a file in my system, but I don't know how to attach the file and attach the file.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {    
         string filepath = @"D:\";

    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|(*.png)|*.png|(*.gif)|*.gif|(*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|";
    openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
    openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try 
        {


        }        
    }
 }
```

I don't know what I have to write in `try` block. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Upload to what? A web page? A service? A file server? Email?

Comment: i want to upload a image from my system and i want to display that uploaded image in my form picture box..... like file upload  control in asp.net web applications.. if i click on button one file will be open in my system...like this..

Comment: can any one pls help me with a bit of sample code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Image.ImageFromFile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx method

Image img = Image.ImageFromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);

Should work.

**EDIT**

If you're going to set it to PictureBox, and what to see complete inside it, use picturebox

[SizeMode](http://this.PictureBox1.SizeMode%20=%20PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;) property.

Comment: thanq tigran its working now but i want to compress the image as i am not able to see the full image ..

Answer (score 1):

```
      using System.IO;

         openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
         openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;        //not allow  multiline selection at the file selection level
         openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Data file";   //define the name of openfileDialog
         openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop"; //define the initial directory


      if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try 
            {
               string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
               FileStream fs=new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //set file stream
               Byte[] bindata=new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)];
               fs.Read(bindata, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
               MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bindata);//load picture 
               stream.Position = 0;
               pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            }        
        }
```