# Deleting a row in a datagrid view when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, delete-row

I have a `form1`  and `form2` ..

**form1**: I have a datagridview with a button column. When I click on the button cell for any row the corresponding row values will be transferred to form2. That was working fine.

**Form 2**: by using setters and getters I have got the values from form1 and I represent the values in textboxes in form 2, and that was fine.

I have a checkbox in form 2. When I click on the check box, I need to remove the row in datagrid view in form 1 (whose row values are transferred to form 2 when I click on the button cell. That row will be deleted from the datagrid view in form1).

How do I fix this?

Comment: i dont know how to delete a row in datagrid view from another form ....when i click on the check box in form 2 the corresponding row will be deleted fro datagrid view in form1..

Comment: `Form2` is the owned by `Form1` right? You should set the DataGrid access modifier `public` in `Form1` (in Form1.designer.cs) in order to access it from `Form2`.

Comment: so would you pls tell how to delete a record from datagrid view...

Comment: can i access the datagrid view row for deleting purpose...

Comment: You want to use `dataGridView.Rows.Remove()` and `dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass data from `Form1` to `Form2`, also pass the row index. It will help you delete the row easily.

Either mark the `DataGridView` of Form1 `public` or pass it as a constructor parameter to `Form2` and then call `DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);` to delete row at the index specified by `rowIndex`.

Comment: Many thanks for the nice answer ...after deleting the row how can i update the datagrid view in form 1 would you pls tell any idea ....

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to delete a record from a grid view from the same form, this is easy.

You can follow the same way as in the answer of Stack Overflow question *[Updating the gridview in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130627/problem-updating-the-gridview-in-one-form/7130747#7130747)*.

As the event arguments you can pass the record ID.

You can use the `RemoveAt` method for deleting a record from the grid view.

```
DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(deleteIndex);
```

But if you share the datasource and remove it from form 2 you need to bind data again to remove from the grid. (See *[How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)* on how to update the gridview.)

If you delete it on the form1 and directly from the gridview, you don't need to bind it again.

Comment: Many thanks .. I have tried the event handler but unfortunately that does not work for me ... and i dont know how to delete a record in same form it self .. any alternative solution pls ....

Comment: `i dont know how to delete a record in same form it self` dataGridView.Rows.Remove() ?

Comment: @DSW how can i update the datagrid view from form2 would you pls suggest any ideas...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
  dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
}
```

Comment: consider providing an explanation to your answer